# Align PrimeNG-components next to each other instead of below each other

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG-components `pInputText` and `p-dropdown` that I'd like to be aligned next to each other. I've got the following code:

```
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="block-div">
  <h4 class="input-description">Enter Information:</h4>
  <span class="ui-float-label">
    <input id="psp-input" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="pspNumber"/>
    <label for="psp-input">{{projectNumber}}.{{pspNumber}}</label>
  </span>
  <h4 class="input-description">Select Type:</h4>
  <p-dropdown [options]="orderTypes" [(ngModel)]="selectedOrderType" [optionLabel]="Typ"></p-dropdown>
  </div>
</div>
```

which produces (confusingly for me) the following output:

[image]

How can I make them aligned next to each other? I wanted to align them in an `inline-block` in my `div`:

```
.block-div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

which worked for native Angular elements, but not for these. I also tried to modify the `width` or align them to two different `div`'s and align them next to each other, which did also not work out. How can I make this work for PrimeNG-Components?

Comment: You should use PrimeNg FlexGrid https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/flexgrid

Comment: Did u get my answer ?

Comment: @selemmn Sorry, I thought I already accepted. Although I am using FlexGrid now, you answer did what I needed. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to group each part (component and its heading) within a simple **`div`** tag:

```
  <div class="block-div">

    <div>

     <h4 class="input-description">Enter Information:</h4>
     <span class="ui-float-label">
      <input id="psp-input" type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="pspNumber"/>
      <label for="psp-input"></label>
     </span>

    </div>

    <div>

      <h4 class="input-description">Select Type:</h4>
      <p-dropdown [options]="orderTypes" [(ngModel)]="selectedOrderType" optionLabel="Typ"></p-dropdown>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Then change your **`css`** to :

```
 .block-div {
   display: inline-flex;
 }
```

**[Working demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-jwx5aj?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)**

Answer (score -2):

Try to group by table and  tr and td tags it is reslove similar problem in p-calendar tags in Edge browser.